# Post JSON request in Qt 4.7

Tags: json, qt

I'm working on a project required me to post JSON request to API server then receive data from server. However I cannot make it work. This is my code

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl("https://www.jusmine.jp/KA/KGBloginCheck");
    QNetworkRequest request(serviceUrl);
    QJsonObject json;
    json.insert("userid","xxxx");
    json.insert("userpass","xxxx");     
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/json");
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader,QByteArray::number(json.size()));
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(networkManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(serviceRequestFinish(QNetworkReply*)));
    networkManager->post(request,QJsonDocument(json).toJson());
}
void MainWindow::serviceRequestFinish(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    QString strReply = (QString)rep->readAll();
    qDebug()<<"Test: "<<strReply;
}
```

After running the program I get nothing from server. (This code is built on Qt 4.7.0 so I have to use library qjson4-master). I don't know if any one can help me in this problem.

This is the result of testing server API:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: are you sure the server is sending any data back? can you receive replies using other tools? try adding `qDebug() << rep->error();` to `serviceRequestFinish` and edit your question with the error that gets printed.

Comment: after adding qDebug() << rep->error(), the program print only "0". As I see in the specification of this network API, this API require me to used "POST HTTP method" and the context-type is "application/json". I don't know if the code that I implemented above  satisfy these requirements.

Comment: If the program prints `0` for `rep->error()` then this means [`QNetworkReply::NoError`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#NetworkError-enum). In the code, you are using POST and the content type header is set to `"application/json"`, there should be no problem with that.

Comment: in the image you posted, the server seems to send an empty response back (with HTTP status code 200), is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes the thing that I want to get from the server is the status "200". How can I get that number ?

Answer (score 4):

You are calculating `ContentLengthHeader` in a wrong way:

```
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, QByteArray::number(json.size()));
```

Please note that [`QJsonObject::size()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#size)  returns the number of (key,value) pairs stored in the object (not the length of its textual representation). Obviously, the header should equal the length of the content not its number of (key,value) pairs.

The code in your `MainWindow`'s constructor should look something like this:

```
QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl("https://www.jusmine.jp/KA/KGBloginCheck");
QNetworkRequest request(serviceUrl);
QJsonObject json;
json.insert("userid","xxxx");
json.insert("userpass","xxxx");     
QJsonDocument jsonDoc(json);
QByteArray jsonData= jsonDoc.toJson();
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/json");
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader,QByteArray::number(jsonData.size()));
QNetworkAccessManager networkManager;
connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinish(QNetworkReply*)));
networkManager.post(request, jsonData);
```

---

**Side Note:** There is no need to calculate Content-Length header yourself, Qt adds this header for you when you don't specify one, see implementation [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/network/access/qnetworkaccessmanager.cpp?h=5.7#n1189). So, You can just omit the line where you add this header.

---

> I want to get the status "200" from the server. How can I get that number ?

In your `serviceRequestFinish` slot, use [`QNetworkReply::attribute()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#attribute):

```
qDebug() << rep->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
```

This should print `200` if your request was ok.